# How to find the enciphering matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, cryptography

For this question I am not sure if I am doing it right. Here is what I have so far. Can anyone please help me out?

If the message UVZR.YH VOYYMNTOSIJXVV was received and it is known
that the Hill 2-cipher was used to encipher it and it is also known that the
message starts with the word DEAR, find the enciphering matrix.

The alphabet is the one used in cryptograhpy and hill 2-ciphers.

$A[4, 5] = [21, 22]$

$A[1, 18] = [26, 18]$

Comment: How can you be unsure whether you're "doing it right" when you haven't done anything?

Comment: I did the first line, but I'm not sure what to do afterwards

Comment: Please show your work then, as far as you got.

Comment: My work is shown so far, but I'm not sure what to do after the first line

Comment: A[4,5] = [21, 22] and A[1,18] = [26, 18]

Comment: I did the first line, which is shown in my comment above

Comment: Stack your equation into a single matrix equation of the form $AB=C$ (where you know $B$ and $C$ as given by two plaintexts and two ciphertexts respectively).  Try to invert $B$ to solve for $A$.

Comment: What is the alphabet order exactly? Does it have both a space and a ., and has it length 29? This is essential knowledge to solve it.

Comment: Hill ciphers don't always have a fixed alphabet, sometimes even the alphabet order is part of the key!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that "DEAR" corresponds to the two vectors $\begin{bmatrix}4\\5\end{bmatrix}$ and  $\begin{bmatrix}1\\18\end{bmatrix}$, if we use the alphabet 
`"_ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ.,"` (underscore for space) where the alphabet length is $29$ (so we are working in $\mathbb{Z}_{29}$ with our linear algebra). The ciphertext starts with "UVZR" which corresponds to $\begin{bmatrix}21\\22\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}26\\18\end{bmatrix}$ under that same alphabet.

So if $E$ is the enciphering matrix we have the matrix equation

$$E\begin{bmatrix}4& 1\\ 5 & 18\ \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}21 & 26\\22&18 \end{bmatrix}$$

So that $$E = \begin{bmatrix}21 & 26\\ 22&18 \end{bmatrix}{\begin{bmatrix}4& 1\\ 5 & 18\ \end{bmatrix}}^{-1}$$

That last matrix has determinant $4 \cdot 18 -5 = 9 \pmod{29}$, which has inverse $13$ modulo 29 (as $9 \times 13 = 117 = 4\times 29 + 1 \equiv 1$; apply the extended Euclidean algorithm to compute it), so that

$${\begin{bmatrix}4& 1\\ 5 & 18\ \end{bmatrix}}^{-1} = 13 \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 18 & -1\\-5 & 4\end{bmatrix}=  \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 16\\22 & 23\end{bmatrix}$$

all modulo $29$ of course. Now find $E$ and then $D$, as its inverse.

I did and found a meaningful message.

Comment: What is D? Why do we need to find it as its inverse?

Comment: And how do we know it has inverse 2 modulo 27 right away?

Comment: @dg123 $D$ is the decryption matrix. You want to decipher the text so eventually you need it.

Comment: But the question asks for the enciphering matrix?

Comment: @dg123 I already told you how to compute $E$

Comment: @dg123 tell us the alphabet order...

Comment: How did you get 7, 0, 17 and 8? Is that from the multiplicative table when you multiply by 2?

Comment: The order is the same as usual except . is 27 , is 28 and - is 0

Comment: @dg123 yes 2 times 17 is 34 and 34 modulo 27 is 7. But apparently I have to use 29.

Comment: How did you get 13 times the matrix after calculating the determinant?

Comment: @dg123 you have to divide by the determinant so multiply by its inverse in the field. The inverse is just found by the extended Euclidean algorithm.

Comment: Ok, did you find the inverse intuitively or did you actually calculate it? If you calculated it, can you tell me how to do it?

Comment: @dg123 look up the extended Euclidean algorithm. You compute the gcd of 9 and 29, and take the Bézout coefficient of 9 modulo 29.